# Laravel Route model binding for packages inside vendor

Tags: laravel, binding, model, routes

**Summary of question: How can I make a "Route Model Binding" on Laravel for a package that keeps the models inside vendor folder?**

**Long version:**

I have managed to get "Chatter" working on a project and now I need to create some admin pages for it. The package's models are inside the vendor directory as follow:

```
vendor\DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models
```

For example the Model "Category" is located at this namespace:

```
vendor\DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models\Category
```

As an example of calling this model if I want to get all the rows:

```
$categories = Models::category()->all();
```

Now I wonder how I can perform a Route-Model-Binding on the models of this package.

If it was a model inside \App folder I would create a function like this inside the controler:

```
function myFunction(\App\Category $category){
    //blah blah
}
```

And inside the route file:

```
 Route::get('doSomething/{category}','MyController@myFunction');
```

But now this wouldn't work. To make it clear the follwoing funciton won't work:

```
function myFunction(\vendor\DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models\Category $category){
   //blah blah
}
```

I get:

```
Class vendor\DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models\Category does not exist
```

How can I create a route-model binding here?

**UPDATE:**
Also this code:

```
function myFunction(\DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models\Category $category){
   //blah blah
}
```

Would throw the same "not found" error.

What baffels me is that the same addressing works at route file for example:

```
Route::get('something/{id}','\DevDojo\Chatter\Controls\myControl@myFunction');
```

It only doesn't work for route binding.

Comment: How 'bout doing the same but ditching the `vendor\ `? Thus using `DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models\Category`

Comment: I get the same error: "Class DevDojo\Chatter\Models\Models\Category does not exist". Strangely the same addressing for Controls work for route file as I am going to add to the original question.